# can I use bool as path parameter (PathParam) using auto route in flutter, and if so, how?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have a payment confirmation route that takes a path parameter of true or false (true when payment was successful and false when unsuccessful). my app should work on both web and mobile. I have used auto_route package for routing and I have defined my route like so:

```
 AutoRoute(
  path: '/business/campaigns/payment_result/:result',
  page: PaymentConfirmationPage,
  guards: [AuthenticationRouteGuard, BusinessAccessRouteGuard],
),
```

and I have given the result like this to my payment page:

```
class PaymentConfirmationPage extends StatelessWidget {
       const PaymentConfirmationPage( {
          @PathParam() required bool result,
           Key? key})
         : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final bool result = context.router.current.pathParams.getBool('result');
        return Container(child: Text(result.toString()));
      }
}
```

However, when I navigate to the page like this:

```
context.router.push(PaymentConfirmationRoute(result: false));
```

I get this error on both web and mobile:

> Class 'bool' has no instance method 'toLowerCase'. Receiver: false
> Tried calling: toLowerCase()

But when I manually enter the route

> domain/business/campaigns/payment_result/false

in my browser, everything works fine.

I could use enums instead, but if bools don't work as pathParams, then why is there a getBool function? Am I making a mistake?

when I click on the relevent error-causing widget printed out in my console, I am directed to the router.gr file, which is generated by auto_route package. below is where I'm lead to:

```
      return _i83.MaterialPageX<dynamic>(
    routeData: routeData,
    child: _i39.PaymentConfirmationPage(
      result: args.result,
      key: args.key,
    ),
  );
```

Comment: where do you call `toLowerCase` in your code?

Comment: I don't call toLowerCase, it happens in my generated router.gr file (generated by the auto_route package), I edited the question for you to see where is happens @eamirho3ein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `String` value to your path, so change your `bool` variable to `String` then inside your PaymentConfirmationPage class try convert it back to `bool` variable if you needed.

I think the reason it has `getBool` method is if you pass `false` as `string`, it will convert it for you and return `bool` variable to you.

Comment: I tried your response, it didn't fix the issue. I still get the same error.

Comment: thank you. It worked. i didn't need to convert the result to boolean though, just changing the type to String in my constructor fixed the issue and getBool worked on it. So yes I guess the purpose of getBool is exactly what you said.